# How to clear unwanted characters in bash

Tags: bash, sed

Actually I have a problem that I can not resolve. Below is partial content of my file:

```
      Slot  Type                     S/N                Version  FPGA version
        1   1 port XFP               0229052008000033   A00           4
--- more --- ^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H        2   4 port 10/100            0138052008000008   D03          10
```

You can see there are unwanted characters which are causing parsing to fail. I am parsing this file with a bash script. I want to get rid of this unwanted characters. I could not find a way to do that with `sed`

Does anybody has a kind of experience? I will really appreciate if he can share with me the way to clear them.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to post you code..

Comment: did you work on the AIX system and get this error?

Comment: Actually this is on Linux , Centos 6.1 and shell is bash. This file is collected with an expect script from the device cli itself. So basically you are connecting to a device cli with expect take the output and then parsing it with a shell script. :)

Comment: `sed 's/\^H//g' file`?

Comment: I faced such problem in my server-status script...do you want to put it for you? maybe helpful

Comment: I will appriciate if you can. I am %100 sure the code is working as there is 15 different same type same OS devices  and they are working fine. The problem here is that this just happened today. This process is working daily. I guess something happened with device CLI and output got this strange characters.

Comment: Sorry BroSlow , I tried this and it did not work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For examplle with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
echo "2---/@@w##z"|sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9\s\/]//g'
# 2/wz
```

Comment: Thanks , I make a small modification to your suggestion and it did work for me. Really appreciated.